# Java - Problem in deploying Web Application

Tags: java, web-applications

I have built a Java Web Application and packed it in a `.war` file and tested it on my local tomcat server and it is running fine.

But when I deployed it on my client's server, it is showing an error. According to the remote server (my client's server), it is not finding a `tld` file packed in a jar file which I had placed in `WEB-INF/lib` directory. But when I checked the `WEB-INF/lib` directory for the jar file, i found that it was there.

The contents of `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` is as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path:
```

I think that there is no need to explicitly mention the classpath of `WEB-INF/lib` directory as it is in the classpath of any web application by default.

Then, why the server can't find the jar file in the `lib` directory when I deployed it on a remote server and why it is working when I deployed the same application on my local server.

I posted a question for this at [Struts 1 - struts-taglib.jar is not being found by my web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441254/struts-1-struts-taglib-jar-is-not-being-found-by-my-web-application) but found that the problem is unusual as nobody could answer it.

So my questions are as follows:

Q1. Is `WEB-INF/lib` still remains on the classpath if I leave the classpath entry blank as shown above in the MANIFEST.MF file or I should delete the classpath entry completely from the file or I should explicitly enter `Class-Path: /WEB-INF/lib` as the classpath entry?

Q2. I have `JSP` pages, `Servlet`s and some helper classes in the web application. Jsp pages are located at the root. Servlets and helper classes are located in `WEB-INF/classes` folder. So Is there any problem if my helper classes are located in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder?

**Note:** Please note that this question is not same as my previous question. It is a follow-up question of my previous question.

Both the servers (local and remote) are tomcat servers.

Comment: Try giving the classpath explicitly.

Comment: one of the classic, "i swear its working on my machine" issues :)

Comment: @medopal nothing funny here... don't post useless comments

Comment: i know its not funny, i have been in similar situations were the deployment machine was a governmental MainFrame, wish i could help

Comment: As far as Q1 is concerned, you've already suggested several things to try. Why not try them?

Comment: Please state the exact versions of Tomcat.  You will most likely find that the target version is too old to support the "tld can be found in jar" facility

Comment: @Thorbhem The tomcat version is 5.0.27

Comment: @medopal upvoted since I think humour should be mandated as an important element for programming. I like SO because the FAQ at http://stackoverflow.com/faq talks about humor :)

Answer (score 1):

Do not create an empty `Class-Path` entry in the manifest, just remove it! Normally you do not need any `Class-Path` entry in a webapp. This entry is more usual for runnable jars.

There is no problem with you helper classes. WEB-INF/classes is always the first entry of the classpath followed by the jars of WEB-INF/lib. So JSPs compiled by the container should have no prblem using classes included there.

Do you have included your taglib in the `web.xml` with an appropiate `taglib-location`?

Comment: All of this is correct. I'll add that I believe .tld files belong in WEB-INF, not WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score -1):

This can happen especially in production if the taglib-location points to an internet location (ie, with http) and the production boxes may not be able to access the internet (due to many firewall restrictions)

Comment: Apparently someone has downvoted a similar suggestion but I am very sure I have faced this problem once before with spring & activemq-core-5.2.0.jar where it validates schema elements. This jar contains a spring.schemas file with the entry http\://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd=activemq.xsd (which indicates to spring about where to find the xsd file) but I had put the schema url wrongly as .../activemq-core-5.2.0.xsd

Comment: the url value of uri attribute doesn't mean that the server has to access internet to find the tld file. Tld files have their own uri that needs to match with the uri of taglib directive to be included